# Time regex issue

Tags: java, regex

I want to return the time format HH:MM am|pm (11:45 AM) or any time matches this regex :

```
    String meridian = "^(0[1-9]|[10-12]):(0[1-9]|[11-59])\\s(AM|PM|am|pm)";
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: `[10-12]` and `[11-59]` do not mean what you think they do.  The `-` in a character group doesn't work for two-digit numbers, so `[11-59]`, means a `1` or `1-5` or `9`.

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions rather than simply trying to parse the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[10-12]` is equivalent to `[1012]` which is equivalent to `[012]`

Similarly `[11-59]` is equivalent to `[123459]`

Use:

```
^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\\s(AM|PM|am|pm)$
```

Comment: how to modify the regex then ?

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` is a set of characters, not numbers.

To match all numbers between `01` and `12`, use `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`.

To match all numbers between `00` and `59`, use `[0-5][0-9]`